# MochaJS, status of unrun tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a suite of MochaJS tests, where it is possible that the body of a `before` block would throw an exception and thus tests in the corresponding `describe` would not be run. I would want to consider such tests as failed.

To add some more context, there is a global `afterEach` which looks up the results of each finished test from `this.currentTest` and sends live updates to a web API.

Can you guys think of any neat way to catch this event (a failed `before`), so that I would there and then be able to marked all of its corresponding tests as failed?

Currently the only thing I can possible think of is simply altering all existing `before` blocks to put their logical body into a `try...catch`, which would be quite painful and very repetitive.

Comment: So what happens when `before` fails? Do all the tests pass?

Comment: You get a failure of the `before` block, but not a failure for each of the tests within. They simply are not reported on by Mocha. This is quite odd.